# Downloading playstore statistics programmatically - Control access to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, google-api-python-client

I am trying to download app install statistics from the google play console  programmatically (using a service account and a client library).

I am following the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en&ref_topic=7071935#zippy=%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-command-line-tool%2Cinstalls%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-client-library-and-service-account%2Csee-an-example-python).

When I run the code, I get the error below:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/o/installs_com.xxx.xxx_201701_overview%2A?alt=json returned "xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.". Details: "[{'message': 'xxxx@xxxx does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">
```

The only thing I didn't explicitly do from the documentation is the one under the heading:

**Control access to Google Cloud Storage**. The part which says:

*"View app information" permission must be set to "Global."*
(I was not sure on how to set this.)

The below is my code (same as what is there in the documentation)

```
client_email = 'xxxx@xxxx.com'
json_file = os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
report_to_download = 'installs_com.xxx.xxxx_201701_overview*'

 
private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')


storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

print (storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket,object=report_to_download).execute())
```

Any support would be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was alright. As per the google play developer support team (thanks to their prompt support), we need to wait for 24 hours after the service account is invited/added on the play console.

After waiting for the recommended time, we can download the data from the storage bucket.

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me hours to debug it and thought it was some IAM setting issues until I saw your post. So I wait and then the next day it works without 403 error.